# Recording and saving sound to file

Tags: objective-c, audio, record, avaudiorecorder

How to record sound and save to file (after that play it)? I need small-size file (as smaller is better) without reduction of bitrate. How can it be implemented on iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello take a look at this [Link](https://gist.github.com/1162105)

also use this:

```
//Reduce or Compress the audio file size 1/4
[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
```